# Use React Dropzone Uploader with custom input field

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, dropzone, react-dropzone

Can I integrate input inside react dropzone uploader? Basically the file I get from input should go to dropzone uploader.

React File Dropzone: https://github.com/fortana-co/react-dropzone-uploader

```
<Dropzone
    maxFiles={1}
    accept="image/*"
    getUploadParams={getUploadParams}
    onChangeStatus={handleChangeStatus}
    multiple={false}
    ref={setInputEl}
>
    <input
        ref={setInputEl}
        accept="image/*"
        className={classes.input}
        id="icon-button-file"
        type="file"
        onChange={handleFileChange}
    />
</Dropzone>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, you can.**

From [the official *live examples*](https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/examples#!/Custom%20Input,%20Directory%20Drag%20and%20Drop):

```
// https://github.com/quarklemotion/html5-file-selector
import { getDroppedOrSelectedFiles } from 'html5-file-selector'

const CustomInput = () => {
  const handleSubmit = (files, allFiles) => {
    console.log(files.map(f => f.meta))
    allFiles.forEach(f => f.remove())
  }

  const getFilesFromEvent = e => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      getDroppedOrSelectedFiles(e).then(chosenFiles => {
        resolve(chosenFiles.map(f => f.fileObject))
      })
    })
  }

  return (
    <Dropzone
      accept="image/*,audio/*,video/*,.pdf"
      getUploadParams={() => ({ url: 'https://httpbin.org/post' })}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      InputComponent={Input}
      getFilesFromEvent={getFilesFromEvent}
    />
  )
}
```

Where `Input` is a custom component you provide:

```
const Input = ({ accept, onFiles, files, getFilesFromEvent }) => {
  const text = files.length > 0 ? 'Add more files' : 'Choose files'

  return (
    <label style={{ backgroundColor: '#007bff', color: '#fff', cursor: 'pointer', padding: 15, borderRadius: 3 }}>
      {text}
      <input
        style={{ display: 'none' }}
        type="file"
        accept={accept}
        multiple
        onChange={e => {
          getFilesFromEvent(e).then(chosenFiles => {
            onFiles(chosenFiles)
          })
        }}
      />
    </label>
  )
}
```

---

To clarify how this is different from your code: you had merely added you custom `<input>` as a child of `<Dropzone>`. You need to do as above so both are correctly "wired" together.

Comment: It says getFilesFromEvent not found. Also I'm trying to insert only 1 file at a time. What does it do?

Comment: Sorry, I had not included everything. But check out the link I included, I got the code from there.

Comment: In my code posted above, why did dropzone uploader couldn't integrate with custom input field?

Comment: Because you had merely added you custom `<input>` as a child of `<Dropzone>`. The custom `<Input>` acts as a "glue" between both so they are correctly "wired" together.

Comment: How to modify code if I just need to upload 1 file?

Comment: I would say remove the `multiple` attribute in `<input>`

Comment: @KillMe there's a prop `multiple` on `Dropzone` you can set to false. `<Dropzone multiple={false} />`. But it looks like you have already done that in your original example.

Comment: @DJ2 You can see that Dropzone's `multiple` attr is not passed to `Input`, and therefore can’t be used by the rendered <input>. In my example, <input> has the `multiple` attr set, so it makes total sense that you can select multiple files.